# NServiceBus equivalent in Java world

Tags: java, .net, nservicebus

Is there any NServiceBus equivalent for Java? I'm not looking for nothing more complicated, even Mule ESB seems to be too much for my needs.

Answer (score 5):

Could be you are looking for http://www.axonframework.org/ ?

> Axon Framework helps build scalable, extensible and maintainable applications by supporting developers apply the Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) architectural pattern. It does so by providing implementations of the most important building blocks, such as aggregates, repositories and event buses (the dispatching mechanism for events)

Comment: not sure why this answer got up voted (perhaps out of kindness?). CQRS is a completely orthogonal concept to an ESB

Comment: NServiceBus isn't an ESB from my point of view. Here is a discussion about it http://stackoverflow.com/a/10845816/327786

Comment: Anyway he is asking for something like NServiceBus, Axonframework has an asynchronous message bus, sagas, etc... I think that NServiceBus is more similar to Axonframework than Mule. Here an example trying to port NServiceBus training example to Axonframework https://github.com/jeffxor/axon-nservicebusclass-example

Answer (score 3):

[Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/) is probably your best bet.  [Udi](http://www.udidahan.com/2010/03/29/esb-differences-between-java-and-net/) has referenced it a few times.